# Command line fails with "Area code is not set" after upgrading to 2.2.3

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento2.2.3, command-line

Custom module takes a dependency on `\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface` and calls `$this->messageManager->getMessages()->getErrors();` after calling other commands.

When this is called this error is thrown:

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  Area code is not set
```

We are setting the area code on the `\Magento\Framework\App\State` prior to calling into `messageManager`.

This didn't happen in magento 2.1.9

```
Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php:154
 Magento\Framework\App\State->getAreaCode() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SidResolver.php:94
 Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver->getSid() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58
 Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Interceptor->___callParent() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138
 Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-staging/Plugin/Framework/Session/SidResolver.php:53
 Magento\Staging\Plugin\Framework\Session\SidResolver->aroundGetSid() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135
 Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153
 Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Interceptor->___callPlugins() at /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/SidResolver/Interceptor.php:26
 Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Interceptor->getSid() at /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/SidResolver/Proxy.php:95
 Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy->getSid() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:186
 Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start() at /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Message/Session/Interceptor.php:24
 Magento\Framework\Message\Session\Interceptor->start() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:130
 Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct() at /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Message/Session/Interceptor.php:14
 Magento\Framework\Message\Session\Interceptor->__construct() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Message/Session/Proxy.php:84
 Magento\Framework\Message\Session\Proxy->_getSubject() at /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Message/Session/Proxy.php:127
 Magento\Framework\Message\Session\Proxy->getData() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Message/Manager.php:120
 Magento\Framework\Message\Manager->getMessages() at /var/www/html/vendor/custom/module/Console/Command/SetupCommand.php:139
 Custom\Module\Console\Command\SetupCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:242
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:843
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:104
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/bin/magento:23
```

I stuck `spl_object_hash($this)` in `/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php` and I've established that the instance of `State` that I'm calling `setAreaCode` on is not the same instance that `SidResolver` is calling `getAreaCode` on.  However I'm not sure if this is just because Magento has serialized the object at some point.

*Update*: Should also point out that this is happening in Enterprise Edition/Magento Commerce and does not happen in the open source version

Comment: Do you have your own command? have you tried `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`?

Comment: This is a command in our own module, after installing the module.  Have also run `setup:di:compile`, doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Add this code to your command file:

```
/**  
 * @var ObjectManagerFactory  
 */ 
private $objectManagerFactory;

/**  
 * @var ObjectManagerInterface  
 */ 
private $objectManager; 

/**  
 * CreateOrderCommand constructor.  
 * @param ObjectManagerFactory $objectManagerFactory  
 */ 
public function __construct(
    ObjectManagerFactory $objectManagerFactory ) {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->objectManagerFactory = $objectManagerFactory; }

/**  
  * Gets initialized object manager  
  *
  * @return ObjectManagerInterface  
  */ 
protected function getObjectManager() {
    if (null == $this->objectManager) {
        $area = FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE;

        $this->objectManager = $this->objectManagerFactory->create($_SERVER);

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState */
        $appState = $this->objectManager-get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
        $appState->setAreaCode($area);
        $configLoader = $this->objectManager-get(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface::class);
        $this->objectManager->configure($configLoader->load($area));
    }
    return $this->objectManager; 
}
```

Then call this `$this->getObjectManager()->get(\{{Module Package}}\{{Module Name}}\{{Your File class path}}::class)`.

Comment: So it turns out adding these 2 lines did it
```$appStateOm = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
$appStateOm->setAreaCode('adminhtml');``` As well as setting `setAreaCode` on the DI injected appState.  Wondering what got you to this idea?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, yes, you can use only this code but other code loads more configurations.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the class where you define your command has an injected class which at some point needs a session (eg: customer session).

Try to isolate that class by commenting one by one in your **`__construct()`** and use a factory class instead.